# using foreach and while together in PHP to generate table

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop

I've done something similar to this table below quite a few times, where I use a **while** statement to populate the `<td>` section of a table, but I've never done it before where part of the `<td>` is populated with a foreach statement, and it's confusing me.

In this example, I create a table, then I populate the first column with a list of suppliers, based on the number of tables inside of my database. (each supplier has its own table).

```
$supplierList = array();
$showTable = "SHOW TABLES from dbOne";
$getSuppliers = mysqli_query($con, $showTable);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($getSuppliers)) {
    $supplierList[] = $row; 
    }
$supplierList = array_reduce($supplierList, 'array_merge', array());
```

Now I have my array that contains the list of all my suppliers, and I use that to generate the `<td>`s in my table.

```
<table>
  <thead>
  <th style="text-align: center;">Supplier</th>
  <th style="text-align: center;">Earliest line</th>
  <th style="text-align: center;">Latest line</th>
  <th style="text-align: center;"># of total lines</th>


  </thead>
  <?php
  foreach ($supplierList as $subList) {
    $supplierName        = $subList;          

    $earlyExp            = "SELECT date FROM $subList ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1" ;
    $earlyExpQuery       = mysqli_query($con, $earlyExp);     
    $lateExp             = "SELECT date FROM $subList ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1" ;
    $lateExpQuery        = mysqli_query($con, $lateExp);
    $countLines          = "SELECT * from $subList";
    $countLinesQuery     = mysqli_query($con, $countLines);    
    $countLinesCount     = mysqli_num_rows($countLinesQuery);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($earlyExpQuery)) {
    $earlyExpDate    = $row['date'];

  ?>  
  <tbody>
  <td><img src = "/img/suppliers/<?= $supplierName ?>.png"></td>  
  <td style="text-align: center;"><?= $earlyExpDate ?></td>
  <td style="text-align: center;"><?= $lateExpDate ?></td>
  <td style="text-align: center;"><?= $countLinesCount ?></td>

  </tbody>
  <?php  
    }
    } 
  ?>
  </table>
```

The table itself builds correctly, and displays each supplier in a unique row.  I cannot figure out though how to populate the other parts of the row with the information based off the unique supplier in the foreach statement.

Comment: Maybe you should tell us how it should be and what you tried.

Comment: Your table does not have <tr>

Comment: Hmm... I've never used <tr> tags before... I've always gone from <table> to <th> to <td>....

Comment: @JohnWu TH is a table header row. TR is a table row. Without TR, your entire table will be one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I sorted this out.  In case it helps anyone else, here's how I did it:

This code goes in the same spot as my post above - so in between the header and the body of the table.  I did not need to use any `<tr>`.

```
<?php
  foreach ($supplierList as $subList) {
    $supplierName        = $subList;          

    $earlyExp            = "SELECT * FROM $subList where dateOne != '' UNION SELECT * from $subList where dateTwo != '' ORDER BY dateTwo, dateOne ASC LIMIT 1" ;
    $earlyExpQuery       = mysqli_query($con, $earlyExp);             
    $lateExp             = "SELECT * FROM $subList where dateOne != '' UNION SELECT * from $subList where dateTwo != '' ORDER BY dateTwo, dateOne DESC LIMIT 1" ;
    $lateExpQuery        = mysqli_query($con, $lateExp);
    $countLines          = "SELECT * from $subList";
    $countLinesQuery     = mysqli_query($con, $countLines);    
    $countLinesCount     = mysqli_num_rows($countLinesQuery);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($earlyExpQuery)) {
    $earlyExpDate    = $row['dateTwo'] ? $row['dateTwo'] : $row['dateOne'];
    }    
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($lateExpQuery)) {
    $lateExpDate    = $row['dateTwo'] ? $row['dateTwo'] : $row['dateOne'];

  ?>
```

They key is that I had to close off each individual **while** statement except the last one - closing that after I closed the `</tbody>` tag but before the `</table>`, like so:

```
</tbody>
<?php  
    }
    } 
  ?>
  </table>
```